# Why is a change in limits of integration necessary here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why did they change the limits and multiply by two? From what I can see the function isn't symmetrical to the x axis for the last few steps
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtX5z.png)

Comment: It is indeed an even function since the sine is squared.

Comment: Because the integrand $8 - \sin^{2}(\theta)$ is an even function over a symmetric interval.

Comment: But the integrand becomes $8-8\sin^3 \theta$... $$(\sin^2 x )^{3/2} = \sin^3 x$$, right?

Comment: Yes, the integrated becomes 8-8sin^3 x , so substituting x for -x, we get 8+8sin^3x. So I thought it isn't symmetrical?

Comment: When integrang even, integral is odd, Difference for full interval is double of half interval. Like $Int- (-Int)= 2 Int $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(-x)$, the with $u=-x$, $du=-dx$, you have 
$$
\int_{-a}^0f(x)\,dx=-\int_a^0 f(u)\,du=\int_0^a f(u)\,du. 
$$
So
$$
\int_{-a}^af(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^0f(x)\,dx+\int_0^af(x)\,dx
=\int_0^af(x)\,dx+\int_0^af(x)\,dx=2\int_0^af(x)\,dx.
$$

What happens in your example is that **first** one does the above, and only then you can write $(\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}=\sin^3\theta$. Remember that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Here, after the symmetry trick allows you to have $\theta\geq0$, one can remove the absolute value (or, equivalently, say that $(\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}=\sin^3\theta$).

Comment: But in this case, isn't the integrand 8(1-sin^3x)? This integrand isn't symmetrical about the x axis I think.

Comment: I have included the explanation.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I understand now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are welcome  :) $ $